# nginx reverse proxy for windows client updates

Tags: nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy

Setup:
Ubuntu 16.04
Nginx 1.14.0
TLS SNI support enabled

I have configured a nginx server as reverse proxy for clients they want 
connect to a WSUS Server (Windows Updates)

Windows Updates Server listen on Port 8530

My configfile:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name wsus.test.de;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/custom/wsus_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/custom/wsus_access.log;


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://wsus.test.de:8530;
    proxy_set_header   Host     $http_host;

  }

}
```

The clients can connect do the Windows Update Server succesfully and get the cab-file.

Then if the clients try to download the needed updates its failed. 
In the local logging i can see the clients try to connect to destination

--> 192.168.3.100:8530

But that ist wrong. The portnumber should be 80 and not 8530. And the servername should be wsus.test.tc and not 192.168.3.100. The clients have to use portnumber 80 because they are behind a firewall (NAT/PAT).

I set in my config:
    proxy_set_header   Host     $http_host;

But dont help.

Have anyone a idea?

Please help

Comment: `192.168.3.100:8530` could be configured somewhere. Check your GPOs / SCCM. Is this your topology: `client -> internet -> wsus.test.de:80 -> LAN -> local-WSUS-server:8530`? Because then your server names are wrong. You are redirecting `wsus.test.de:80` to `wsus.test.de:8530`, which _should_ be the same (your Ubuntu) host.

Comment: The 192.168.3.100 is the ipaddress of the wsus-server. I have to different security zones client -> firewall(NAT/PAT) -> nginx-server --> wsus server. On the firewall i have to use the portnumber 80 for windows updates but the windows-update-server listen on port 8530. The Firewall sends all port 80 traffic to my nginxserver and the nginxserver sends the traffic to the windows-update-server. Its exist no policys or something else. The clients are managed through puppet.

Comment: the wsus-server is a standalone server and its not a domain-member

Comment: All in the same LAN? Hm...I'd ditch the nginx reverse and use classic DNAT/SNAT 80:8530 maybe, or just use port 80/443 instead. The clients should _always_ connect to your nginx, they should never see IP 192.168.3.100. But for real: why don't you open Port 8530 on your firewall for this server?

Comment: The clients cant see the ipaddress 192.168.3.100 because the traffic goes through a firewall they do natting. The idea is we work on nginx with server_names and forward the traffic to the backend-server. On the firewall we just open port 80 and port 443. The entire http/https traffic goes through the nginx and he looks to the server_name and forward traffic. All works fine except the wsus-server. Because the wsus-server write in the cab-files the wrong server_name and portnumber. If we dont find a solution we will open the port 8530 on our firewall.